# How to return to the initial definition of quote on markdown, after having redefined it? That definition is unknown or can vary depending on flavors

Tags: latex, markdown

After having redefined `quote` in markdown to create nice blockquote with background color and borders, how can I return to the previous `quote` definition,
that is unknown, because it's markdown who initialized it first, and I don't know how, with what?

Here is the *pdf* display showing the problem I'm encountering: I decide to put a green background with borders on blockquotes, then I cannot remove this background and borders entirely when I decide to so...
I haven't a way to be sure to go back to the previous state that prevailed before.

The *pdf* is followed the markdown file that produced it.

[image]

```markdown
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{fvextra}

geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
output: pdf
classoption: fleqn
---

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\newcommand{\cadreAvantage}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=green!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=green!75!black,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}
\newcommand{\cadreAttention}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}
\newcommand{\cadreTransparent}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=white!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,lowerbox=invisible,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}

I begin a text, and then do a blockquote `> ....`

   > Here a normal blockquote: I don't know how _markdown_ defines it  
   > it's the classical one, without border, nothing: only a left padding

Then, I wish to put some text under a green blockquote

\cadreAvantage

   > This blockquote will be more visible  
   > Nice green, it is really attractive

But how to go back to the previous blockquote shape, the one that comes with markdown?

   > If a do another blockquote without changing anything, its still green

Defining `quote` to nothing with a `\renewtcolorbox{quote}{}` doesn't return to normal:

   > I have cancelled `quote` definition here  
   > It's grey...

I have a workaround : defining a transparent blockquote

\cadreTransparent

   > But it still have borders, I cannot remove them,  
   > and its not really what previously existed.

How may I rollback `quote` to its previous definition?  
considering that I don't really know what it was, only markdown knows how it initialized `quote` (it might even depend even on your operating system, distro, environment flavor...)

so that they will look as if I'd never changed them...  

\cadreAttention

   > Until I decide doing so again?

I believe that I don't really need to know what this initial definition is.  
I think (but you might have a better idea) that what I need is to be able to save it once, and to restore it each time its needed.

So that I will have command in my markdown like:

/saveQuote
abc
/cadreAvantage
   > def
/restoreQuote
jkl
/cadreAttention
   > mno
/restoreQuote
   > this one is the normal blockquote
```

(the pdf file is created by a `pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures test.md -o test.pdf` command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of switching back to the original definition, you can limit your modifications to a part of your document, if you place them inside a group:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  - \usepackage{fvextra}
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: fleqn
---

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newcommand{\cadreAvantage}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=green!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=green!75!black,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}
\newcommand{\cadreAttention}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}
\newcommand{\cadreTransparent}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=white!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,lowerbox=invisible,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}

I begin a text, and then do a blockquote `> ....`

   > Here a normal blockquote: I don't know how _markdown_ defines it  
   > it's the classical one, without border, nothing: only a left padding

Then, I wish to put some text under a green blockquote

\begingroup

\cadreAvantage

   > This blockquote will be more visible  
   > Nice green, it is really attractive

But how to go back to the previous blockquote shape, the one that comes with markdown?

   > If a do another blockquote without changing anything, its still green

Defining `quote` to nothing with a `\renewtcolorbox{quote}{}` doesn't return to normal:

   > I have cancelled `quote` definition here  
   > It's grey...

I have a workaround : defining a transparent blockquote

\endgroup


   > But it still have borders, I cannot remove them,  
   > and its not really what previously existed.

How may I rollback `quote` to its previous definition?  
considering that I don't really know what it was, only markdown knows how it initialized `quote` (it might even depend even on your operating system, distro, environment flavor...)

so that they will look as if I'd never changed them...  

\cadreAttention

   > Until I decide doing so again?

I believe that I don't really need to know what this initial definition is.  
I think (but you might have a better idea) that what I need is to be able to save it once, and to restore it each time its needed.

So that I will have command in my markdown like:

/saveQuote
abc
/cadreAvantage
   > def
/restoreQuote
jkl
/cadreAttention
   > mno
/restoreQuote
   > this one is the normal blockquote
```

[image]